# Configuring server startup of SeleniumRC in NetBeans

Tags: testing, netbeans, selenium, selenium-rc, netbeans-plugins

I want the logs from the Selenium Server Console write to file.
I know how to do this if i start server frome console (cmd.exe)

> java -jar selenium-server.jar -log logfile.txt

But i run selenium test in NetBeans and selenium server start from NetBeans.
I can to set port and way to start for the selenium server
screenshot url: 
![alt text][1]http://www.screencast.com/users/Display_ACH/folders/Jing/media/f0982c5e-0c27-4dee-a684-0ed9c0c09a4e

Can I to set option "log" for server which i run with NetBeans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this question. I will run a server separate from NetBeans. I learned, what NetBeans uses the old version of Selenium (1.0.1) and this the version can`t work with FF 3.6